# Android NFC Android Application Records Error

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I am trying to add an application record using `createApplicationRecord(packagename)` as mentioned in the [Android developer link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) to my `NdefMessage` and I see an error:

> The method createApplicationRecord(String) is undefined for the type NdefRecord

I have updated my Android SDK Manager from Eclipse. Here is the part of code:

```
private NdefMessage getMessageAsNdef() {
    byte[] textBytes = mInfo.getBytes();
    NdefRecord textRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,
            "text/plain".getBytes(), new byte[] {}, textBytes);
    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { textRecord, NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.nfcgeo.mypackage") });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your project settings in Eclipse have set the Android "Project Build Target" to API level 14 or higher. `NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord()` is only available in Android 4.0 ICS and later.